# Entity Framework create tables or fields if using dbfirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The project uses dbfirst approach. On my database I create and edit tables , Then I update the models from the database (edmx).
Is there a way to solve the problem when my models are more relevant than the customer base? It is very important to solve this with the help of EF.
That is, I need to in the customer database automatically added new fields in the tables and created the tables themselves if they were not

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio over your database model through the designer interface and them updated your database. However, it's a procedure i don't recomend you to do, because depending what operations you want to perform on your database after being applied can rise errors related with some specific types and other specific things and then the roolback could not be so easy.